# How do I get the first install date of a disk drive in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query, powershell-5.1, cim

In the *Device Manager*, I can view the properties of any device (disk drives included). In the *Details* tab, I can select the *first install date*:

[image]

In PowerShell, I can get all disk drives by issuing:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_DiskDrive
```

The returned objects have an `InstallDate` property, but it is empty. How can I get the date, that is visible in the device manager, in PowerShell? Do I have to associate the `CIM_DiskDrive` class with another CIM class? If so, which?

Comment: FYI: You can't trust the date shown in Device Manager. I checked the Samsung NVME drive in my main driver and it shows May 2021. Not quite I purchased it in 2018!

Comment: @RetiredGeek Does it relate to the last semi-annual Windows Upgrade in your case?

Comment: funny you should ask...and the answer is ... YES Exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the excellent pointer from [Almighty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489326/11942268) I came up with the following solution:

```
Get-PnpDevice -Class DiskDrive -Status OK | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FriendlyName=(Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InputObject $_ -KeyName DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName).Data;
        FirstInstallDate=(Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InputObject $_ -KeyName DEVPKEY_Device_FirstInstallDate).Data
    }
}
```

It gets all currently installed disk drives and returns their friendly names and first install dates as a custom object for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Get-PnpDeviceProperty` you can pull the additonal info that you're looking for. It is not as intuitive as you would think, but it does work! I am sure you can find the exact Class and pull it directly, but this is a functional way nonetheless.

```
# Get PNPDeviceID from the disk driver
$PNPDeviceID = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_DiskDrive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PNPDeviceID

# Get friendly name to verify and first install date
Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InstanceId $PNPDeviceID -KeyName DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName, DEVPKEY_Device_FirstInstallDate | Select-Object KeyName, Data
```

Comment: Excellent pointer! Be aware that this solution won't work with multiple disks installed.

Comment: Neat, I like your revision